# Running the program to show current directory contents in eclipse gives a result which seems confusing

Tags: java, eclipse, working-directory

I have this program:

```
System.out.println("files: ");
        dir = new File(".");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(f -> {return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".java");});

        System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath());

        for (String f: dir.list()) {
            System.out.println(f);
        }
```

I am running the program from eclipse which gives me the following result:

```
files: 
C:\Users\rezbi\workspace\Misc\.
.classpath
.project
.settings
bin
src
```

This is confusing because the current directory is supposed to be the classes or bin directory with all the class files. Please enlighten.

Comment: where is `files` used?

Answer (score 4):

When running a Java program in Eclipse, you can define which directory to use as the *Working directory* in the launch configuration. By default this is the location of the project, not the `bin` subfolder. (Even though you can easily change it to that if you like.)

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks for your taking the time to take the screenshot. I am still confused. If the program is being run then conceptually it is gonna be run using the command: java CurrentClass and the working folder is supposed to be folder containing CurrentClass (that is with respect to the class/program being run). Not sure how does eclipse's working directory have anything to do with it.

Comment: Well, in the end, Eclipse is the one who decides *where* to run your program, if you launch it from Eclipse ;-) If you run your program via any other means (say with `java -jar ...` from the command line) then the working directory will be the one from which you launch it.

Answer (score 2):

This is specific to how Eclipse runs your applications from within IDE. Your projects's root is default option for program's working directory.

You can manually set program's working directory (and many other options!) from "Run Configurations.." menu item.